# SYMFONY DEV to PROD: \DebugBundle not included by AppKernel.php in PROD case creates issue with all existing dump(...) functions in the code

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7, symfony-3.1, symfony-3.2

In SYMFONY3, I use intensively in my code the dump(...) function of [The VarDumper Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/var_dumper.html) that works with the [DebugBundle Configuration ("debug")](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/debug.html).

Once you move to the production settings all the `dump(...)` that are in the code become an issue and throws errors because in [project]\app\AppKernel.php the setting looks like that:

```
class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = [...];

        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), ['dev', 'test'], true)) {
            $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle();
            ...     
        }

        return $bundles;
    }

.... other functions...
}
```

`Symfony\Bundle\DebugBundle\DebugBundle()` is meant to work in 'dev' environment only. I could add it to the 'prod' environment but it is, for obvious performance reasons, not meant to be like that.

It means that one has to delete (or comment) all the `dump(...)` in the code. I have quite a lot of it, so I wonder if there is a recommendation, regarding that specific topic, to move smoothly from "dev" to "prod" .

Comment: Well dump is a debug command so the idea is to remove all the dump statements before going to production.  But I have gotten caught a few times when I forget.  As a quick work around, just add "function dump() {}" to web/app.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `prod` environment you have to remove all `dump()` calls at all. Thats why Symfony use `dump` function only in `dev` environment and not allow you to run code with that function in `prod` environment.

Also it is not so good to have `dump()` statements all around the code. You can test some parts of your code with this useful function but when you know that your code works well you can remove `dump()` statement immediately. And you will not have any problems in the future.

You can use any of IDEs to replace all occurrences of `dump()` to empty string and so you will have working code in `prod` environment.

Comment: Of course: replace the dump() with empty string:)) it was so obvious it did not occur to me:))

Answer (score 1):

The best way be to remove all the dumps, obviously, but here is a workaround you could try.
You should create a PHP [closure](http://php.net/manual/en/class.closure.php) that does nothing. This way, the calls to the dump function will have no effect at all.
I haven't try this, so let me know if you have any problems.

```
// web/app.php
function dump() {
    return;
}
```

Comment: I don't know, but if it doesn't you could create a custom Twig function using Twig Extension. https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/twig_extension.html